# How to pass information to new function

Tags: javascript

Need to know how to pass the information of username, caption, and formImg to addNewPost from handleFormSubmit

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
   // This next line prevents the reload of the form
   event.preventDefault();
   // Get values of inputs
   // Pass values to addNewPost()
   var username = document.getElementById("formUsername").value;
   var caption = document.getElementById("formCaption").value;
   var formImg = document.getElementById("formImg").value;

function addNewPost(username, caption, imgLocation) {




}
```

Comment: you can call `addNewPost(username, caption, formImg)` in your `handleFormSubmit` function. Make sure `addNewPost()` is declared outside your `handleFormSubmit` function

Answer (score 2):

You can call the `addNewPost` function inside `handleFormSubmit` function and can pass the values.

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
   // This next line prevents the reload of the form
   event.preventDefault();
   // Get values of inputs
   // Pass values to addNewPost()
   var username = document.getElementById("formUsername").value;
   var caption = document.getElementById("formCaption").value;
   var formImg = document.getElementById("formImg").value;

   addNewPost(username, caption, formImg ); // call the function here.
}
function addNewPost(username, caption, imgLocation) {


}
```